# Is passing a JSON between Javascript and Flask a secure way to convert a JSON to a CSV in flask?

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

On my flask app I want to create a feature so a user can query the database, have the browser display the results in a table and then download it in a csv.

Is the plan I have below secure?  Would end users be able to manipulate the JSON?

My overall design plan to accomplish this is as follows in pseudocode:

- (Python) pulls Query from database and puts results in JSON using JSONIFY
- (Python) returns JSON to Javascript file
- (Javascript) Displays the JSON in an HTML table
- (Javascript) User clicks button and Javascript sends JSON to flask endpoint
- (Python) Flask endpoint converts JSON into CSV

Comment: *" Would end users be able to manipulate the JSON?"* Of cause. Like everything in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

Re-sending the JSON to the Flask server seems a useless waste of bandwidth (since the server already has this information). The Flask server should be able to generate a CSV representation, directly from the database query, for example using a csv.writer or csv.DictWriter object.

Comment: I see, so on the python/flask side I can simply store the JSON in some session or globe variable and then run the python function when the user hits the button?

Comment: Well, I imagined re-running the query (instead of storing the JSON from the previous execution), to get "fresh" results ad and avoid session memory consumption and the risk of having stale results.
In a way, you may have a single API endpoint, that will deliver the same result, either in JSON format or in CSV format (depending, maybe, on a `format=csv` request parameter)

Comment: I see what you are saying.  Initially I wanted to ensure the tables on the screen matched the document, but if the contents are updated in the mean time, it would make sense that the csv should be updated.

Comment: yes, that's what I thought. But it depends on your specific requirements, of course.